# How can I make Flatlist with 2 column display limited items and continue in a carousel?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, react-native-flatlist

I have a list of about 28 items, I made it into 2 columns, It works fine but now I want to show only only the first 10 items and the next 10 will be in the second page of a carousel. I have tried to no avail. I need help please.

this is a shorter version of the code.

```
function CategoriesScreen(props) {
  const CATE = [
    {Item: "1"},
    {Item: "2"},
    ...
    {Item: "28"},

  ];


  return (
    <Screen>
      <View style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          data={CATE}
          numColumns={2}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.card}>
              ...display items
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}
export default CategoriesScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
onEndReached={this.retrieveMore}
```

read more here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached